# Data stored in local storage returns undefined until page reload in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, local-storage, lazy-loading, react-context

I am working on an app which on login, stores the role to the local storage. The role is supposed to redirect the user to the desired page. But on save, it returns as `undefined`. I have to reload the page in order for the main role `auth.role === 'admin'` to be checked.

Is there any way I can make this work without returning an `undefined` route?

```js
const AdminRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  const auth = useContext(AuthContext)
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
        auth.token && auth.role === 'admin' ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/',
              state: { from: location },
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  )
}
```

This is my `signIn` function:

```js
const signIn = async (email, password, callback) => {
    setLoading(true)
    const { data } = await signInApi(email, password)
    console.log(data)

    if (data && data.token) {
      localStorage.setItem('token', data.token)
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(data.user))
      localStorage.setItem('role', data.user.role)
      setToken(data.token)
      setUser(data.user)
      setUser(data.user.role)
      callback()
    }
    setLoading(false)
  }
```

Comment: shouldn't the setLoading(false) should be between the brakes of the if(data && data.token)? you are pretty much doing:

setLoading(true)
setLoading(false)

Comment: I do not understand. Could you modify code for me?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `useEffect` hook with dependencies if data of local storage is changed to trigger `useEffect` a `setRole` change to the current role:

```
useEffect(() => {
  storageRole = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("role"));
  setRole(storageRole); //you can store role of user in state as role and setRole
}, [storageRole]);
```